# Truth table logic

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

Can someone please show me how this works, i'm going out of my mind

I know the truth tables for the individual AND, OR AND NOT but when it comes to them being combined my understanding is shattered into pieces =/

[image: Truth table]

Comment: Do you understand the third column?

Comment: Are you familiar with the symbols?

Comment: I'm familiar with the symbols and the truth tables for each symbol. But when they're combined together i just can't grasp it. Also, how difficult/long do you think this subject will take to learn for someone who's a novice at maths :P trying to revise it for my Jan exam / very important that i understand it

Comment: Some programming experience would help. I'm gonna start posting my answer now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take it one step at a time, creating extra columns if needed.

For example, for $p \lor (q \land \lnot p)$:

- Make your $p, q$ columns as you did.
- Then create a column for $\color{blue}{\lnot p}$, and fill in the truth values (reversing the truth values that are listed in the "p-column"
- Then create a column headed by $q \land \color{blue}{\lnot p}$, "and-ing" the $q$-column and the $\lnot p$-column.
- Finally, create a column headed with $p \lor (q\land \lnot p),$"or-ing" the $p$-column and the $(q \land \lnot p) column.

That way you're just needing to focus on one connective at a time.

Comment: hey thanks, although for : http://vvcap.net/db/dIfNA89LjoYY11Yt4i8T.htp                        I don't understand some o these answers for the second column since it's AND i thought it was only true when both are true, yet some are putten down as true when both p and q are not both true..

Comment: $\lnot(p \land q)$ is true whenever it is NOT the case that both $p$ and $q$ are true.

Comment: Ah ok, i thought it meant not p and not q so i was just converting their t and f =  )

Comment: @amWhy: Very clean answer +1

Comment: $\ddot\smile$+1

Answer (score 1):

Before getting into the truth table let's clarify the following statements:

$P \wedge Q$ is true when $P$ and $Q$ are the same , for instance:

if $P$ is TRUE and $Q$ is FALSE $P \wedge Q$ returns FALSE.

Moreover: if $P$ is FALSE and $Q$ is FALSE $P \wedge Q$ returns TRUE.

Negation $\neg$ will set the opposite value to the variable.

For instance, if $P$ is FALSE $\neg P$ (Not P) will return TRUE.

From this, we can conclude that if $P \neq Q$ then $P = \neg Q$.

Disquction (or) will return TRUE if any of the variables are TRUE.

if $P$ is FALSE and $Q$ is TRUE then $P \vee Q$ will return TRUE.

if $P$ is FALSE, $Q$ is FALSE and $S$ is TRUE then again $P \vee Q \vee S$ will return TRUE.

Now, regarding your question, you can try to make your life a little easier by setting the inner parenthesis as another boolean variable.

Example:

If $P$ is TRUE and $Q$ is FALSE:

In the logic statement $P \vee (Q \wedge \neg P)$ :

Let $A$ be  $\neg P$ .

Since $P$ is TRUE , $\neg P$ returns FALSE.

let $B$ be $Q \wedge A$.

Since $Q$ is FALSE and A is FALSE, $Q \wedge A$ returns FALSE.

So, $P \vee (Q \wedge \neg P)$

will return TRUE, since $P$ is TRUE and the whole parenthesis is FALSE.

This example is the result of your 3rd line, if I'm correct.

Answer (score 0):

First since you have 2 variables the table will have 4 rows. First you complete the column under p,q such that all 4 cases appear. Then you complete the column for $r=\lnot{p}$. Then using the column for q and the column for r you complete the column for $s=(q\land r)$.
Finally using the column for p and the column for s you complete the column for $(p \lor s)$.
In each step you use the truth tables for AND, OR, NOT you already know.
Does this help?